# How do you install ssh-copy-id on a Mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, homebrew, ssh-keys

I am having trouble trying to install ssh-copy-id on my Mac. I have tried to follow https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX  but every time I run ssh-copy-id it gives me errors. Any ideas on how to get ssh-copy-id to install?

Comment: how do people upvote a question instead of an answer?

Answer (score 346, accepted):

You can install it using [Homebrew](https://github.com/homebrew/brew):

```
brew install ssh-copy-id
```

If you don't want to use Homebrew, you can use [this Mac port](https://github.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX):

```
curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/beautifulcode/ssh-copy-id-for-OSX/master/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: First gave me errors, but it turned out my brew library was a bit overdue for a refresh. Running `brew update` and then installing again solved the problem.

Answer (score 27):

MacPorts version: `sudo port install openssh +ssh-copy-id`

Answer (score 6):

`ssh-copy-id` is installed on macOS by default now.

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.4

$ which ssh-copy-id
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
```

Answer (score 6):

The above methods do not work on old Macs. I have a lion OS. use this instead because the ssh-copy-id can not be installed with brew on old PCs due to compiling dependencies errors at ssl.

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@123.45.56.78 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

credit goes to [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2)

Comment: You left out the `chmod 700` from your linked site.  You could instead use:  `ssh USER@HOST 'umask 077 && mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'`

Comment: Both merged together is: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_name.pub | ssh <username>@192.168.1.X 
"mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"` - it works for my old mac - `El Capitan`

Answer (score 0):

install [homebrew](http://brew.sh)
then `$ brew install ssh-copy-id`

Comment: This just duplicates the accepted answer from 2 years earlier..