# Concatenating a local file with a remote one

Tags: bash, macos, ssh

These three lines of code require authentication twice. I don't yet have password-less authentication set up on this server. In fact, these lines of code are to copy my public key to the server and concatenate it with the existing file.

**How can I re-write this process with a single `ssh` command that requires authentication only once?**

```
scp ~/local.txt user@server.com:~/remote.txt

ssh -l user user@server.com

cat ~/remote.txt >> ~/otherRemote.txt
```

I've looked into the following possibilities:

- command `sed`
- operator `||`
- operator `&&`
- shared session: [Can I use an existing SSH connection and execute SCP over that tunnel without re-authenticating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949316/can-i-use-an-existing-ssh-connection-and-execute-scp-over-that-tunnel-without-re)

I also considered placing `local.txt` at an openly accessible location, for example, with a public dropbox link. Then if `cat` could accept this as an input, the `scp` line wouldn't be necessary. But this would also require an additional step and wouldn't work in cases where `local.txt` cannot be made public.

Other references:

[Using a variable's value as password for scp, ssh etc. instead of prompting for user input every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594698/using-a-variables-value-as-password-for-scp-ssh-etc-instead-of-prompting-for)

https://superuser.com/questions/400714/how-to-remotely-write-to-a-file-using-ssh

Comment: Have you tried the `ssh-copy-id` command? It does this automatically for you.

Comment: I would need to install that. Do you see any advantage over the solution below? Would it work more easily in a bash script? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25655450/how-do-you-install-ssh-copy-id-on-a-mac

Comment: `ssh-copy-id` does some additional stuff, like creating `~/.ssh` if necessary, and making sure that the permissions are correct. But other than that, it's essentially equivalent to the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the content to the remote, and then use commands on the remote to do something with it. Like this:

```
ssh user@server.com 'cat >> otherRemote.txt' < ~/local.txt
```

The remote `cat` command will receive as its input the content of `~/local.txt`, passed to the `ssh` command by input redirection.

Btw, as @Barmar pointed out, specifying the username with both `-l user` and `user@` was also redundant in your example.